# htaccess: Redirect from subdomain.test.com/~user77 to www.testing.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, url-rewriting, temporary

I want to redirect from a temporary URI like

http://subdomain.test.com/~user77/

to

http://www.testing.com

This is a temporary URI and points to the same webserver. All requests like

http://subdomain.test.com/~user77/index.php 
http://subdomain.test.com/~user77/lib/javascript.js

should be redirected to

http://www.testing.com/index.php 
http://www.testing.com/lib/javascript.js

How can I achieve this? I have the following htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://subdomain.test.com/~user77/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.testing.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. If I input subdomain.test.com/~user77 I see the same URL (subdomain.test.com/~user77). What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Full htaccess:

```
#####
# 
# Example .htaccess file for TYPO3 CMS - for use with Apache Webserver
# 
# This file includes settings for the following configuration options:
# 
# - Compression via TYPO3
# - Settings for mod_rewrite (URL-Rewriting)
# - PHP optimisation
# - Miscellaneous
# 
# If you want to use it, you have to copy it to the root folder of your TYPO3 installation (if its
# not there already) and rename it to '.htaccess'. To make .htaccess files work, you might need to
# adjust the 'AllowOverride' directive in your Apache configuration file.
# 
# IMPORTANT: You may need to change this file depending on your TYPO3 installation!
#
# Lines starting with a # are treated as comment and ignored by the web server.
# 
# You should change every occurance of TYPO3root/ to the location where you have your website in.
# For example:
# If you have your website located at http://mysite.com/
# then your TYPO3root/ is just empty (remove 'TYPO3root/')
# If you have your website located at http://mysite.com/some/path/
# then your TYPO3root/ is some/path/ (search and replace)
# 
# You can also use this configuration in your httpd.conf, but then you have to modify some lines,
# see the comments (search for 'httpd.conf')
# 
# Questions about this file go to the matching Install mailing list, see
# http://typo3.org/documentation/mailing-lists/
# 
####


### Begin: Compression via TYPO3 ###

# Compressing resource files will save bandwidth and so improve loading speed especially for users
# with slower internet connections. TYPO3 can compress the .js and .css files for you.
# 1) Uncomment the following lines and
# 2) Set $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] = '9'

#<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/css" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#AddEncoding gzip .gzip

### End: Compression via TYPO3 ###


### Begin: Browser caching of ressource files ###

# Enable long browser caching for JavaScript and CSS files.

# This affects Frontend and Backend and increases performance.
# You can also add other file extensions (like gif, png, jpg), if you want them to be longer cached, too.

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </IfModule>
  FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>

### End: Browser caching of ressource files ###


### Begin: Settings for mod_rewrite ###

# You need rewriting, if you use a URL-Rewriting extension (RealURL, CoolUri, SimulateStatic).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Change this path, if your TYPO3 installation is located in a subdirectory of the website root.
#RewriteBase /

# Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

# Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory.
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

# Redirect http://example.com/typo3 to http://example.com/typo3/index_re.php and stop the rewrite processing.
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/typo3$ /TYPO3root/typo3/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
# For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Main URL rewriting.
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule .* /TYPO3root/index.php [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

### End: Settings for mod_rewrite ###


### Begin: PHP optimisation ###

# If you do not change the following settings, the default values will be used.

# TYPO3 works fine with register_globals turned off.
# This is highly recommended, if your web server has it turned on.
#php_flag register_globals off

### End: PHP optimisation ###



### Begin: Miscellaneous ###

# Make sure that directory listings are disabled.
#Options -Indexes

### End: Miscellaneous ###


# Add your own rules here.
# ...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://subdomain.test.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^~user77/(.*)$ http://www.testing.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://subdomain.test.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^~user77/(.*)$ http://www.testing.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately it doesn't work. If I input subdomain.test.com/~user77 I stay on this page and I will not be redirected. When does the change of the htaccess file takes effect?

Comment: Immediate. Try `http://subdomain.test.com/~user77/` and see if you are redirected. If so the trailing slash is the issue.

Comment: With and without the slash it's the same (nothing happens). Also if I input http://subdomain.test.com/~user77/images/251356.jpg ... The updated file is on the server, but it is called _.htaccess. Perhaps thats the problem? PS: How do you make the code highlighting in the comments?

Comment: File should be called `.htaccess`. See if that's the issue as this `RewriteRule` should work (minus the trailing slash). As far as the code in comments, check out [Markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I removed the underscore, but the result stays the same. `http://subdomain.test.com/~user77/` as well as `http://subdomain.test.com/~user77` doesn't trigger the redirect.

Comment: I wanted to check if `mod_rewrite` is loaded as Apache module. But I even can't find the `apache2handler` section ... How can I check if mod_rewrite is loaded? The provider seems to exclude that from the phpinfo? I even tried with `RewriteBase /`. In addition, `RewriteEngine On` was always present ..

Comment: I can't answer those questions. I suggest you update your question with your full htaccess code to see if you get more answers and contact your hosting provider.

Comment: I will contact the hosting provider. I also updated my question with full htaccess. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You already have Rewrite Rules further up for your TYPO3 software. I would try testing by tempoarly removing those rules to see if you are even getting to the lines you are placing at the bottom.

You can test the redirects at http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/